# comparing three categorical columns and representing the results with 0,1 or 2

Tags: r, if-statement, comparison, multiple-columns, categorical-data

How can I compare the categorical content of one of my columns with the content of 3 others? For example, if the data of x is the same as the one of y it will be represented by 0, is it the same as the v it will be represented by 1 and if the same as z by 2.

```
x<- c(C,T,T,G,A,A,T,C,G)
y<- c(C,G,G,T,G,C,C,A,T)
v<- c(A,C,T,C,G,G,T,A,C)
z<- c(CTC,CCT,ATC,AC,T,CC,GC,AC,CTAC)
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hei there!

You can use dyplr and its `case_when()` argument to define multiple if-statements:

```
# define data
x<- c("C","T","T","G","A","A","T","C","G")
y<- c("C","G","G","T","G","C","C","A","T")
v<- c("A","C","T","C","G","G","T","A","C")
z<- c("CTC","CCT","ATC","AC","T","CC","GC","AC","CTAC")

dat <- data.frame(as.character(x), as.character(y), as.character(v), as.character(z))

# create new column considering your desired conditions
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(new_column = case_when(x == y ~ 0,
                                x == v ~ 1,
                                x == z ~ 2,
                                TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```